# Validation of hidden section in Sitecore Forms causes inconsistent behavior for File Upload field

Tags: sitecore-forms

I have a File Upload `forms` field in 2 sections.
Depending on some conditions one of the sections is hidden.

The form cannot be submitted because the validation of fields is failing if the section which contains a mandatory field is hidden.

On `Sitecore 9.3` was a similar bug: https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0821778

But I can replicate the issue on `Sitecore 10.2`. For other forms fields (`Single line text`) works as expected.

Comment: Do you have the submit button outside both sections? Or do you have a button for each section?

Comment: it's a general button on the page

Comment: Vlad Iobagiu, did you get any fix for this? Please share if you have fixed or made any work around for this...